# excel- count the most repeated value

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the most unpaid user in a excel table. Column A has account numbers and B has paid date( unpaid once are blank). I found out which once are the unpaid by using(column C)

```
=IF(B2<>"","Paid","Not Paid")
```

How can I count which account has the most unpaid? or just the blank cells and display the account number?

``````
=INDEX(A2:B266408,MODE(MATCH(A2:B266408,A2:B266408,0)))
`````(This returns #N/A)
``````

can someone help please

[image]

Comment: Please update this question with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Are you just trying to do this as a once-off task, or do you need a formula which dynamically updates with the content?

Comment: Maybe this is enough? `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$266408,"",A$2$:$A$266408,A2)` . Then drag down.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I am trying to get a formula that updates with the contain

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I Uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

- **Occurance** `C2` `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A2,A2,B$1:B2,"=")`
- **Max occurance** `E2` `=MAX(C:C)`
- **Account number** `F2` `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,$C:$C,0))`

This will find the first **Account number** that has the heighest **Occurance**.

## Updated screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks !! But this returns the value zero for Column E and F..

Comment: Did you carefully place the "$" in the occurance formula? They make sure, that only occurances until the current row are counted.

Comment: @Ran: Or are the cells in `B:B` not blank? If they e.g. contain a " ", then you will have to adjust the **occurance** formula accordingly. Please post a screenshot of your table in which you use the formulas given in this answer.

Comment: when I try with random data on a separate sheet your formula worked. My account numbers has both Letters and numbers, is that the issue?

Comment: No, that should not be an issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data that reflect your real needs.

Comment: can you explain how can I find the next 2 most repeated. I am sorry if i am asking for too much.